# Initialize Dictionary inline in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary

I'm trying to find a way to initialize a Dictionary inline in ActionScript 3, like:

```
private var sampleDic:Dictionary = new Dictionary (
   { "zero", "Hello" },
   { "one", "World" }
);
```

I tried many ways, but none works. Anyone knows if it's possible, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do it. You have to construct a dictionary and then add the values in a loop or individually.

Answer (score 6):

If it's static you can do this with a block

```
private static var myDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
{
     myDict["zero"] = "Hello";
     myDict["one"] = "World";
}
```

Comment: Is this sort of thing a common theme among object-oriented languages?  I've never seen anything like this, except for the first line.

Answer (score 4):

If you REALLY want something like that, you can use a Dictionary factory:

```
    public class DictFactory 
    {
        public var dict:Dictionary;
        public function create(obj:Object):Dictionary
        {
            dict = new Dictionary();

            for (var key:String in obj) {
              dict[key] = obj[key];
            }

            return dict;
        }           
    }
```

Usage:

```
private var sampleDic:Dictionary = new DictFactory().create({ "zero":"Hello", "one": "World" });
```

The `DictFactory.create` expects a Object with key-values, that will be applied to the returned Dictionary, if you pass any other object (in AS3, any class is Object), results may be undesireable. :)

Comment: Didn't think of that, thanks a lot. I actually need objects as keys, but I can manage something like that that will allow them.

Comment: In my example you can use any objects as key or values

Comment: Ow, you're right. Sorry I spent the last months using C# and now my mind is crafting new non-existing limitations for ActionScript. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend dictionary class and override default constructor with one that accepts initial key-value pears.

**EDIT:**

You can also use this dirty JS like solution :)

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

var dict : Dictionary = function ( d : Dictionary, p : Object ) : Dictionary { for ( var i : String in p ) { d[i] = p[i] }; return d; }(new Dictionary(), {
   "zero": "Hello",
   "one": "World"
})

trace( dict["zero"] );
```

Comment: Nice, that's thinking outside of the box.  Does it slow stuff down or anything though, or is it basically just as efficient?

Comment: You won't feel performance impact if don't execute in very ofter (few thousand times per frame :) ). The problem with this approach is that you can use only Strings for keys. That means that you get no extra functionality than from Object. So a a better thing is to create some wrapper or factory class around Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason to use a Dictionary you can do it with an object.

```
private var sample:Object = {
   "zero": "Hello",
   "one": "World"
};
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct. I have corrected it but it doesn't show up yet.  Anyway, this will work fine when the keys are strings, but not for any other type. Given the example in the question, probably strings are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks but no. I used a simple example, but in reality I need keys that are not strings